# Is there a way to change the background color for different R-studio sessions?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to have multiple session of Rstudio to tackle different use cases. And I wish to change the colors of the background to distinguish them. I am not able to find anything useful in Global options.

I know we can do this in terminal while using just base R but Rstudio is a different case.

Comment: Could you add a picture of what it looks like when you do this in base R? Thanks :)

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2350

There's an feature request raised for the same on Rstudio.